# read only databases and index fragmentation in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, indexing

I have a number of read only databases `alter database [ReferenceData] set READ_ONLY` that is used by our application and was wondering what type of things I can tweak for maximum performance?

So far, I came up with the following goals:

- Force padding in indexes to 100% fill factor
- index fragementation be less than 10%
- If space isn't a problem look at DMVs and add as many INCLUDED columns as recommended

Do these make sense? Are there more things I should be tweaking for max efficiencies?

I'm running SQL Server 2008 on Windows 2008

Answer (score 1):

This might sound kind of obvious but you don't outright say you've done it in your question so I'll mention it:

1. Are you sure all the proper indexes
   are in place?  You might run
   profiler/DTA against the DB to see if
   there are any areas that could be
   potentially improved by creating new
   indexes.
2. Have you performance tuned the
   queries that use the read only DB? 
   All the indexes in the world don't
   matter if you have poorly written
   queries.

Comment: yes, you are correct about properly written code and choice of indexes but my question is more specifically about what can be done when the database is read-only versus a read-write database.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase
SET READ_ONLY
```

will set a database into a non-modifiable state.  Presumably there are some optimizations there, but I'm not sure.

You can also set the default transaction level to be READ UNCOMMITTED for maximum read performance for each session.  Presumably if you set your database to read-only mode, this is already happening though.

EDIT:  Ran across [this article](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1921) about what you should to to prep a database for being read-only.

Comment: i'm not sure, but i sure hope that when its read-only the database the engine knows it can read without locks. My database has been read-only for years now (except during updates monthly) and  i'm just trying to figure out what can be done to keep it optimal.

Comment: Thanks for the link. That post mentions mentions performance benefits would be no need for locks, extra indexes have no impact, and 3rd, and not sure why this is perf related, but you can copy data and log files while the database is online